# How to add an Image into a JavaFx TableView column

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx, tableview

I'm trying to find a way to add an image to a JavaFx TableView column that has data in other columns populated from a H2 database via hibernate. The TableView has been designed in JavaFx Scene Builder.

This is what I've managed to put together so far:

***The Controller Class:***

```
public class HomeController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<NewBeautifulKiwi> KIWI_TABLE;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<NewBeautifulKiwi, Image> KiwiId;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<NewBeautifulKiwi, String> Kiwi;

    public ObservableList<NewBeautifulKiwi> data;

    // Initializes the controller class.
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        KiwiId.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<NewBeautifulKiwi, Image>, TableCell<NewBeautifulKiwi, Image>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<NewBeautifulKiwi, Image> call(TableColumn<NewBeautifulKiwi, Image> param) {
                //Set up the ImageView
                final ImageView imageview = new ImageView();
                imageview.setFitHeight(50);
                imageview.setFitWidth(50);

                //Set up the Table
                TableCell<NewBeautifulKiwi, Image> cell = new TableCell<NewBeautifulKiwi, Image>() {
                    public void updateItem(NewBeautifulKiwi item, boolean empty) {
                        if (item != null) {
                            imageview.setImage("arrow.png");
                        }
                    }
                };

                // Attach the imageview to the cell
                cell.setGraphic(imageview);
                return cell;
            }

        });

        Kiwi.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<NewBeautifulKiwi, String>("Kiwi"));
        KIWI_TABLE.setItems(gobbledyGook());
    }

    private ObservableList<NewBeautifulKiwi> gobbledyGook() {
        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            List courses = session.createQuery("from KIWI_TABLE").list();
            for (Iterator iterator = courses.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                NewBeautifulKiwi course = (NewBeautifulKiwi) iterator.next();
                System.out.println(course.getKiwi());

                data.add(course);
            }
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

I get an error at `imageview.setImage("arrow.png");` that says `Incopatibletypes: String cannot be converted to Image`.

This is my very first time trying to add an image into a TableView.

I've looked around since yesterday, but I now seem to be stuck. I was hoping for some help. I would really appreciate some help.

***This is the class that creates the database pojos:***

```
@Entity(name = "KIWI_TABLE")
public class NewBeautifulKiwi implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int KiwiId;
    private String Kiwi;

    public int getKiwiId() {
        return KiwiId;
    }

    public void setKiwiId(int KiwiId) {
        this.KiwiId = KiwiId;
    }

    public String getKiwi() {
        return Kiwi;
    }

    public void setKiwi(String Kiwi) {
        this.Kiwi = Kiwi;
    }
}
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Ref:http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/10/01/tableview-cell-modifiy-in-javafx/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Update

Since the link doesn't work and I had multiple requests to update it, I am updating this with a new answer.

From the question, I am unsure if OP wants the image to be loaded from some field in `NewBeautifulKiwi` or does he wants to show the same image for all the data. So, I will answer for both the approaches.

**Note:** *Approach 1 doesn't make much sense to me and exists only because I am confused about OP's requirement. The question is ~4 years old and I don't think clarifying from OP will have any impact. The suggested approach to handle these kinds of problem is 2.*

---

1. Load the same `arrow.png` for all the rows

Code:

```
KiwiId.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<NewBeautifulKiwi, Integer>, TableCell<NewBeautifulKiwi, Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public TableCell<NewBeautifulKiwi, Integer> call(TableColumn<NewBeautifulKiwi, Integer> param) {
      ...
      TableCell<NewBeautifulKiwi, Integer> cell = new TableCell<NewBeautifulKiwi, Integer>() {
         public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
            if (item != null) {
              imageview.setImage(new Image("arrow.png"));
            }
         }
      };
      // Attach the imageview to the cell
      cell.setGraphic(imageview);
      return cell;
    }
 });
 KiwiId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<NewBeautifulKiwi, Integer>("KiwiId"));
```

---

2. Load the Image from the a property in `NewBeautifulKiwi`. Since the column `TableColumn<NewBeautifulKiwi, Image> KiwiId;` seems like it should bind itself to a property image which is missing from `NewBeautifulKiwi`. I will introduce it and later use it to bind to this column's (renamed to 'kiwiImageCol') cell value factory.

Code:

```
@Entity(name = "KIWI_TABLE")
public class NewBeautifulKiwi implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int KiwiId;
    private String Kiwi;
    private Image kiwiImage;

    public int getKiwiId() {
        return KiwiId;
    }

    public void setKiwiId(int KiwiId) {
        this.KiwiId = KiwiId;
    }

    public String getKiwi() {
        return Kiwi;
    }

    public void setKiwi(String Kiwi) {
        this.Kiwi = Kiwi;
    }

    public Image getKiwiImage() {
        return kiwiImage;
    }

    public void setKiwiImage(Image kiwiImage) {
        this.kiwiImage = kiwiImage;
    }
}
```

In the table, I will bind the TableColumn to this new property

```
...
@FXML
private TableColumn<NewBeautifulKiwi, Image> KiwiImageCol;
...
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    KiwiImageCol.setCellFactory(param -> {
       //Set up the ImageView
       final ImageView imageview = new ImageView();
       imageview.setFitHeight(50);
       imageview.setFitWidth(50);

       //Set up the Table
       TableCell<NewBeautifulKiwi, Image> cell = new TableCell<NewBeautifulKiwi, Image>() {
           public void updateItem(Image item, boolean empty) {
             if (item != null) {
                  imageview.setImage(item);
             }
           }
        };
        // Attach the imageview to the cell
        cell.setGraphic(imageview);
        return cell;
   });
   KiwiImageCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<NewBeautifulKiwi, Image>("kiwiImage"));
}
```

---

### Outdated Answer

You forgot to bind the KiwiId with a `CellValueFactory`. Please go through the following example which uses a VBox in a column as it needs Image and a label. You may directly use a ImageView

https://blogs.oracle.com/javajungle/entry/how_to_pretty_up_your

Everything is described very nicely. Incase you still have doubts feel free to comment !

Comment: I appreciate the blog example a lot.  It got me almost to where I need to be, but I'd like to see your model for the example.  I'm trying to add a tableColumn<colorLegend, Circle> and I cannot figure out how to add the Circle "property" in the colorLegend class.  Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind I found it. It needs to be an ObjectProperty.  but I really appreciate the nice blog, that helped out a lot.

Comment: Why Oracle post images of code and not copyable code? What is wrong with them?

Comment: @BrianStallter if you still remember, can you post what fix this please?

Comment: well there is no circle property, but in order to make the cell factory you need a property in your model that corresponds to the column you are creating.  I was looking at how to get a "circle property", there is no circle property, but object properties do exist so I used that.

Comment: I hope that answers your question.  I'm not sure what part you were stuck on exactly.

Comment: Updated answer as per request

Answer (score 0):

Your present error can be removed if you use following statement

```
imageview.setImage(new Image("arrow.png"));
```